# Leaving data blank if no condition is satisfied in Nested IF

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a formula that will place a symbol, if my due date is less then today's date, and if my due date is more then todays date. I am trying to include leaving the cell blank, if neither applies but can't figure it out. Here is my formula now:

```
=IF(D3<A1,CHAR(40),IF(D3>A1,CHAR(254)))
```

`D3` is my due date and `A1` is todays date.

Comment: deleted half my formula... this is the whole thing:=IF(D3<A1,CHAR(40),IF(D3>A1,CHAR(254)))

Comment: The syntax of `IF` is `IF(logical_test,[value_if_true],[value_if_false])`. You can substitute additional `IF` statement(s) for the `[value_if_false]`, but the final `[value_if_false]` will always be what the formula will return if none of the foregoing truth conditions are satisfied.

Therefore, your formula is:
`=IF(D3<A1,CHAR(40),IF(D3>A1,CHAR(254),""))`

Answer (score 0):

Your IF formula is incomplete. If you decide to use IF formula, you will have to include a detailed formuala as per below:

=IF(D3$A$1,CHAR(254),""),"")

My work around is to include another column with a formula calculating the difference between today's date and the due date. According to that answer (if its plus or minus or zero) I would use conditional formatting to highlight the rows (less than today's date would be red, etc.)

Comment: `=IF(D3$A$1,...` this is not going to work